# Prevent overwrite of Docker image tag in Azure Container registry

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I have seen in the official docs that Docker images can be locked so that they cannot be deleted.
Is it also possible to freeze a tag so that this tag can no more be overwriten to point to a different image?

My usecase is that I want to make sure that e.g. an image with tag 1.2.0 always points to exactly the same image for all times. The tags 1.2 and 1 may be moved but this "semvar" tag shall be stable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Azure lock cannot apply to the image tags. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources#how-locks-are-applied) is the description for the level that it can apply to:

> Resource Manager locks apply only to operations that happen in the
> management plane, which consists of operations sent to
> https://management.azure.com.

You can use the [Azure role-based access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) to restrict whether the user can push or pull images. But in this way, the limit will only implement on the repository, not deeper into the tag.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping to get but at least now I know what is available.
Thank you